# What is disadvantage of using CTE?

Tags: sql-server

I am just pretty curious and actually don's know what are the disadvantages of using CTE? I know the advantage but I just want to know the disadvantages, much thanks.

Comment: Disadvantage compared to what?

Comment: Without more specific question it's difficult to answer - but for me personally the main "issue" is because of the way SQL Server handles the structure versus how easy they are too use - then I've often see complex usage of CTE which would be better suited for temp tables and/or dedicated tables - but to call it a disadvantage is incorrect as it's more a misuse.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117/65699 - What's the difference between a CTE and a Temp Table? There's some listed there.

Comment: well, actually, i dont know compare to what, cuz this is an interview question, so i am assuming that he wanna ask the disadvantage over temp table

Answer (score 1):

One limitation of CTE that I find is that the scope of CTE is limited to only the next sql statement after cte definition.

```
;WITH cte As (SELECT col1,col2, Row_number() over(partition by col3 order by id) as rowNum
FROM table) 

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rowNum=1
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rowNum >1 -- ERROR occurs as cte defined can be used only uptil next statement of cte definition done by using WITH clause
```

Comment: I wont say this as disadvantage. Then there wont be any difference from table variable or temp table

Comment: @Prdp The scope of table variables and temporary tables are different than common table expressions.

Comment: well if you are writing your script from scratch you can take descision whether CTE is required or table variable beforehand. But if you get code with large CTE defined and need further functionality to be acheived using resulteset returned by CTE you cant use CTE itself but to insert resultset into table variable or rewrite the CTE as table variable or temp  table .

Comment: Honestly, that is the only so-called disadvantage that i can think of.....but what you said also make sense to me.

Comment: please add this  and cite sources, c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b5eb6a/common-table-expression-in-sql-server